# Android startActivityForResult very slow

Tags: android, android-intent

I am calling an activity using `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`, and then setting the result of my activity when a calendarview is changed and then `finish();` ing the activity. But when I call `startActivityForResult();` it takes forever to load the activity.Here is how I launch the SecondActivity: 
in the oncreate:

```
calendar = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setClass(this, CalendarShow.class);
```

and on a fling gesture:

```
  @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                                startActivityForResult(calendar, 0);

            return true;
        }
```

Here is code for the second activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_show);
        CalendarView v = new CalendarView(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        v.setFocusedMonthDateColor(Color.BLACK);
        v.setUnfocusedMonthDateColor(Color.GRAY);
        v.setSelectedWeekBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        v.setWeekNumberColor (Color.TRANSPARENT);
        v.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400));
        v.setId(99);
        v.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                    int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Intent ret = new Intent();
            ret.putExtra("year", year);
            ret.putExtra("month", month);
            ret.putExtra("day", dayOfMonth);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, ret);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up2, R.anim.slide_out_up2);
        }

    });
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.calendarLayout);
        layout.addView(v);
    }
```

EDIT:
I tried starting the activity just normal, without the ForResult and it was still slow.

Comment: can you show the code for the activity that you're starting?

Comment: is it slow also without overridePendingTransition?

Comment: @lelloman it is slow when the second activity starts. I will take away overridePendingTransition and see how it is.

Comment: @lelloman nope, still a 5 second delay between when I call the method and the activity starts

Comment: 5 seconds seems too much, unless you're trying it on an emulator, which can be very slow

Comment: @lelloman I am on an s3 and it is about 4-5 seconds

Comment: @lelloman I will time it

Comment: 4-5 seconds to load this activity on s3 sounds weird, could you post the code for launching the activity?

Comment: @lelloman yes. is it the device?

Comment: @lelloman here, see the code

Comment: @lelloman also, when the animation is performed the screen is black, and then it changes

Comment: I think it would be better to call `overridePendingTransition()` just after `startActivityForResult()`, as transitions probably need to be loaded **before** changing activity, not when the second one is already created.

Comment: @miNde tried, but still not working

Comment: `CalendarView` is a complex widget and trying to put it in a constrained layout causes it to lay out very slowly. Try to simplify the `RelativeLayout` where you're putting it and if the problem persists, update the question with the relevant layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you are not supposed to start an activity on a fling gesture, and when you do, it takes a long time to load, so you could change the activity to a fragment.